# Passing a vector object to a function by reference?

Tags: c++, class, vector

How do I correctly ask for object rock in main. I simplified the code, figuring this was the only problem. The error "expected primary-expression before '&' token.

```
void createObject(vector <object>& obj, world wld)
{

....

}

int main()
{
object rock;
createObject(vector<object>& rock, level_1);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is not clear what you're trying to do. Do you want to pass an `object` to the function or a `vector<object>`? The `vector<object>& rock` syntax is completely wrong for passing an argument.

Comment: Please learn basic C++ syntax. **Please.**

Comment: To a vector object. I figured that. But I also get an error when just using rock. error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'std::vector<object>&' from expression of type 'object

Comment: @Dljcali You seem to have a bad understanding of functions, arguments, and calling functions. `createObject` is declared as a function that takes two arguments: one is a reference to a `vector<object>` and the other is a `world`. You therefore **must** pass a `vector<object>` and a `world` to that function when you call it. You have declared `rock` as an `object`, so of course you can't pass that! An `object` is not the same as a `vector<object>`!

Comment: That solves it. I didn't know that about vectors. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Very simply:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<object> rock_vector(1);
    createObject(rock_vector, level_1);
}
```

You can't pass `rock` to it, as it's not a `vector`. You need to pass an actual `vector` to it. Here, I made `rock_vector` of size 1, so it's at least got one `object` in it (so `rock_vector[0]` is more or less your replacement for `rock`).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification on that. I couldn't figure out the relationship of object and vector before.